# Show $\mathbb{P}($drawing all balls with a uneven number from 2n numbered balls (without replacement)) is $\frac{n!}{2^n \cdot \prod_{j=1}^n (2j-1)}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, solution-verification, binomial-coefficients

The balls are numbered from $1$ to $2n$
$$\mathbb{P(e)} = \frac{n!}{2^n \cdot \prod_{j=1}^n (2j-1)}$$

My attempt at showing that:

$\mathbb{P(e)} = \frac{\# \space ways \space to \space draw \space n \space \space balls \space with\ uneven \space numbers\space from \space 2n \space balls \space (without \space replacement) \space =: \space A}{\# ways \space to \space draw \space n \space balls \space from \space 2n \space balls \space (without \space replacement) \space =: \space B} $

For A:
There are $n!$ permutations where each specific ball is in the set of the drawn balls.

For B: For the first element we have $2n$ possible balls to draw, for the next ball we have $2n-1$ possibilities and so on = $2n\cdot(2n-1)\cdot(2n-2) \cdot \space ... \space \cdot \space(2n-(n-1)) = 2n\cdot\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (2j-1)$

So $$\frac{A}{B} = \frac{n!}{2n\cdot\prod_{j=1}^{n-1} (2j-1)}$$

Now obviously $2n \ne 2^n$ and the product also has different indices, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $2n$ balls numbered from $1$ to $2n$ there are $n$ odd-numbered balls. So we want the probability of drawing all of those in any order, out of $n$ extractions without replacement. The probability of a particular successful event is
$$\frac{1}{2n}\frac{1}{2n-1}(...)\frac{1}{n+1}=\frac{n!}{2n!}$$
The total number of arrangements of odd numbers is $n!$ so
$$P=\frac{(n!)^2}{2n!}$$
This is equal to the needed result. Indeed
$$\prod_{j=1}^{n}(2j-1)=1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot (...)\cdot (2n-1)$$
$$\prod_{j=1}^{n}2j=2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot (...)\cdot 2n$$
So
$$\frac{(n!)^2}{2n!}=\frac{(n!)^2}{\prod_{j=1}^{n}(2j-1)\prod_{k=1}^{n}2k}$$
and
$$\frac{n!}{\prod_{k=1}^{n}2k}=\frac{n}{2n}\frac{n-1}{2(n-1)}\frac{n-2}{2(n-2)}(...)\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^n}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I think in the first product of fractions there are the $(n \cdot (n-1) \cdot ... \cdot 1)$ missing that make up $n!$

Comment: @WhatAMesh notice where the product of the denominators stops

Comment: Ah now I get that, too.